# many to many mysql with tricky condition

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Please, check my tables below

users

```
id name  
1  John
2  Peter
3  Predator
```

phones

```
id name 
1  apple
2  nexus
3  nokva
```

phones_users

```
phone_id user_id
1        1
2        1
2        2
3        3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e02f3/2)

Ok, I want to get a result like this:

```
phone_id  phone_name user_id user_name
1         apple      1       John
2         nexus      1       John
2         nexus      2       Peter
```

I tried one request, but it doesn't work expectedly

```
select `phones`.`name` as `phone_name`, `phones`.`created_at`, `phones`.`id`, `users`.`name` as `user_name`, `users`.`id` as `user_id` from `phones` left join `phones_users` on (`phones`.`id` = `phones_users`.`phone_id` and `phones_users`.`user_id` = 1) left join `users` on `phones_users`.`phone_id` = `phones`.`id` where `users`.`name` is not null;
```

I want to get all the phones that have the user with ID = 1, and all users who have phones that belonged to him..

For example, John has apple and nexus and Peter has nexus, I want to get a table with apple, nexus, John, Peter.

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attached a copy of phones_users and used IF to distinguish, whether the phone belongs to the same person or not. Based upon that I output the user name and id.

```
SELECT
    `phones_users`.`phone_id`, 
    `phones`.`name` AS phone_name, 
    IF(`users`.`id` = `users2`.`id`, `users`.`id`, `users2`.`id`) 
       AS `user_id`,
    IF(`users`.`id` = `users2`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `users2`.`name`) 
       AS `user_name`
FROM
    phones_users
INNER JOIN
    phones
ON
    phones_users.phone_id=phones.id
INNER JOIN
    users
ON
    phones_users.user_id=users.id
INNER JOIN -- here I attach the copy of the table
    phones_users AS phones_users2
ON
    phones_users.phone_id=phones_users2.phone_id
INNER JOIN
    users AS users2
ON
    phones_users2.user_id=users2.id
WHERE
    phones_users.user_id=1;
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| phone_id | phone_name   | user_id | user_name |
+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|        1 | apple iphone |       1 | John      |
|        2 | nexus        |       1 | John      |
|        2 | nexus        |       2 | Peter     |
+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- We know the user details for this part of the query, so just hard-code them instead of query for them
    SELECT phone_id, (SELECT name FROM phones WHERE id = pu.phone_id) AS phone_name, 1 AS user_id, "John" AS user_name
    FROM phones_users pu
    WHERE phone_id IN (SELECT phone_id
                       FROM phones_users
                       WHERE user_id = 1)
UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id AS phone_id, p.name AS phone_name, u.id AS user_id, u.name AS user_name
    FROM phones p, user u
    WHERE u.id IN (SELECT user_id
                   FROM phones_users
                   WHERE user_id != 1
                     AND phone_id IN (SELECT phone_id FROM phones_users WHERE user_id = 1))
      AND u.id = (SELECT user_id
                  FROM phones_users
                  WHERE phone_id = p.id)
```

Transcribed to English:

Select the `phone_id` from the table `phones_users` where this id is in the list of ids of phones used by John and the name of the phone with this id and the values 1 (the ID of John) and his name, "John".
Then, append to that (here it starts to get even more complicated):
the phone id and name and user id and name from the rows resulting from joining the tables `phones` and `users`, but only on the rows satisfying the following constraints:

- The user id of the row is in the list of user ids of users whose phone's id is the same as the id of the phone John (the user with id 1) uses, i.e. this user is not John but uses the same phone as John,
- and the user id is in the list of user ids that are in the table `phones_users` in the same row as the phone id of the joined row, i.e. this user does indeed use this phone (joining the tables `phones` and `users` will give all possible combinations, so we have to remove the rows in which people are with phones they don't use).

I hope you can understand the transcription and the query, if not feel free to leave a comment.

DISCLAIMER: I didn't test the query, it may not work.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your example and got this "Reference 'phone_name' not supported (forward reference in item list): SELECT phone_id, (SELECT phone_name FROM phones WHERE id = pu.phone_id) AS phone_name, 1 AS user_id, "John" AS user_name FROM phones_users pu WHERE phone_id IN (SELECT phone_id FROM phones_users WHERE user_id = 1) UNION ALL SELECT p.id AS phone_id, p.name AS phone_name, u.id AS user_id, u.name AS user_name FROM phones p, users u WHERE u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM phones_users WHERE user_id != 1 ..."

Comment: @JohnSmitt Whoops, that `phone_name` should have been just `name`. I'll edit.